# Dovecot Disconnected Unexpectedly?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have an issues with Dovecot? I am using this with Postfix, which as far as I can tell is working fine. I have setup a user `contact`, which when I send mail to seems to be picking it up and when I send mail (via my Webmin access) it sends it out, STMP is being handled by Mailgun.

However I can not seem to get any Email client, Outlook, Apple Mail etc to talk to the server.

I have set up this `contact` user within my Outlook, using only the IMAP protocol. It seems to sync up (or at lest it did) for getting emails down, e.g. I can see the two emails I sent to that account. But I can not seems to send any emails out? Like I say, I think my STMP setup is fine with Mailgun but for some reason Outlook and my dovecot server will not work?

I have, though looks of research, found this very useful command, doveadm user, which when run with the setup conf file before, returns

`Error: userdb lookup(contact@domain-name.com): Disconnected unexpectedly`

I think I should add that this is running on a copy Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Conf Settings:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = *
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    address = *
    port = 993
  }
}

disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_location = maildir:/home/%u/Maildir

userdb {
  #args = username_format=%n
  driver = passwd
  #driver = pam
}

passdb {
  args = username_format=%n
  #driver = pam
  driver = passwd
}

protocols = "imap"

auth_username_format = %n
auth_mechanisms = plan login

namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes

  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }

  mailbox Sent {
   auto = subscribe
   special_use = \Sent
  }
}

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }

  unix_listener auth-master {
    mode = 0666
  }
}

ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/mail.key
ssl = yes
```

Please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: You seem to be confusing a few things.  Is your Outlook configured with Mailgun's SMTP server?

Comment: @julie Nope, only Postfix is using Mailgun as a STMP relay. I have configured my Outlook (I have also tried Apple Mail) to use IMAP pointing both to my domain. But that I think the problem is, that Dovecot is not using the system users details to auth. and I don't know why doveadm is giving me that error.

Comment: To simplify your confusion, `Dovecot` is an IMAP server and is not involved in the email delivery.

Comment: Sorry I am not confused I know that. My question is about IMAP dovecot setup? Have I not asked that in the question? I have learn issues which makes explain a problem. I have no problem with SMTP and postfix, that all works, but I want my dovecot to let me login to the mail boxes which I cant do as it does not let me?

Comment: Here's a quick guess:  try increasing `mail_max_userip_connections` and I suspect your problem will be resolved.

Comment: @julie that seems to have fixed my issues. Post it has an answer and I accept it! - I did a bit of reserach on that, as I had ever seen that setting before, I have set it to 20, what would be the best or most avage connections to be set? Many thanks.

Comment: You'd have to play around to find what works best but I doubt you really need 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error can often be caused because the email client opens simultaneous connections for different operations.

A simple solution is to increase the number of simultaneous connections by increasing the `mail_max_userip_connections` setting.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install `dovecot-mysql`:

```
apt install dovecot-mysql
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not going to fix the problem reported in the question.